# Installing SQL Server on Ubuntu 16.04 failure

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, package-management, updates

I have been trying to install SQL server and been following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu
Here are the results;

```
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

output

```
-
[sudo] password for user:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0    162      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--   217

OK
```

then

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list)"
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:100    87  100    87    0     0     36      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    36
```

and then I get this `E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server/pool/main/m/mssql-server/mssql-server_14.0.900.75-1_amd64.deb  Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 120 seconds`

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated  mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core libasyncns0:i386
  libexif12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjson-c2:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libogg0:i386
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-4.8.0-36
  linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gawk libc++1 libjemalloc1 libsigsegv2 libsss-nss-idmap0
Suggested packages:
  gawk-doc clang
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gawk libc++1 libjemalloc1 libsigsegv2 libsss-nss-idmap0
  mssql-server
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 172 MB/173 MB of archives.
After this operation, 909 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.10-4 [14٫1 kB]
Get:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial/main amd64 mssql-server amd64 14.0.900.75-1 [172 MB]
17% [2 mssql-server 491 kB/172 MB 0%]                                                                                                       Err:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial/main amd64 mssql-server amd64 14.0.900.75-1
  Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 120 seconds
Fetched 14٫1 kB in 3min 32s (66 B/s)    
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server/pool/main/m/mssql-server/mssql-server_14.0.900.75-1_amd64.deb  Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 120 seconds
```

Tried apt-get update, no help.